# How can I adjust sales percentages by population?

Tags: statistics

In my data below, I can figure in my head that regions A and B will end up roughly equal, but I can't figure out how to calculate it.

$$
\begin{array}{crr}
  region & \% \text{ population} & \% \text{ sales} \\\hline
  A & 49.1 & 83.0 \\
  B &  5.5 &  9.1 \\
  C & 31.8 &  4.5 \\
  D &  3.7 &  2.3 \\
  E &  9.9 &  1.1
\end{array}
$$

Comment: how long did this take to type ? you know you can do arrays and matrices on this site right if not see about MathJax

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As @Roddy mentioned, MathJax is a great help to posting mathematics questions. A short guide is at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I can't even get MathJax to work in my attempts to edit the posting.

Comment: @dantopa Thanks for making the table.  The help kept telling me to use Markdown and I've never seen MathJax before.

Comment: What is it about the regions you're trying to calculate?

Comment: @pjs36 I thought I could somehow "normalize" (perhaps the wrong term) the sales percentages to reflect that the regions have significantly different sized populations.  If there's a better way to represent this, I'd be interested in that too.

Answer (score 2):

As you thought about it, "normalize" the results to get, for example,
$$\begin{array}{crr}
 \text{ region} & P & S & \frac SP\\
A&  49.1 & 83.0 & 1.690 \\
 B &5.5 & 9.1 & 1.655 \\
C & 31.8 & 4.5 & 0.142 \\
D &  3.7 & 2.3 & 0.622 \\
E & 9.9 & 1.1 & 0.111
\end{array}$$